# How to select values from string separated by comma in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to select values from string separated by comma (,) in SQL Query,
I tried with the following query but it gives only 3 columns
and I want like 8 columns

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(DB_field, CHARINDEX(',', DB_field)-1) as '1st column', 
  SUBSTRING(DB_field, CHARINDEX(',', DB_field)+1, LEN(DB_field)-CHARINDEX(',', DB_field)-CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(DB_field)))  as '2nd column',
  RIGHT(DB_field, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(DB_field))-1)   as '3rd column'
FROM Table_Name
```

**DB_field** has string value but separate by comma (,) something like **123,456,789,abcd,efghjk,lmno,pqrs,tuvw**
How can I select that values from that string in SQL Query?

Please anyone can help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: This question has been asked many, many, many times before. Please use your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML-based solution:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
    (N'123,456,789,abcd,efghjk,lmno,pqrs,tuvw'),
    (N'987,654,321,dbca,kjhgfe,onml,srqp,xyz')
    ) as t(DB_field)
)

SELECT  t.c.value('/a[1]','nvarchar(max)') as [1column],
        t.c.value('/a[2]','nvarchar(max)') as [2column],
        t.c.value('/a[3]','nvarchar(max)') as [3column],
        t.c.value('/a[4]','nvarchar(max)') as [4column],
        t.c.value('/a[5]','nvarchar(max)') as [5column],
        t.c.value('/a[6]','nvarchar(max)') as [6column],
        t.c.value('/a[7]','nvarchar(max)') as [7column],
        t.c.value('/a[8]','nvarchar(max)') as [8column],
        t.c.value('/a[9]','nvarchar(max)') as [9column]
FROM (
    SELECT CAST(('<a>'+REPLACE(DB_field,',','</a><a>') +'</a>') as xml) as x
    FROM cte c
) as xt
CROSS APPLY xt.x.nodes('/') as t(c)
```

Output:

```
1column 2column 3column 4column 5column 6column 7column 8column 9column
123     456     789     abcd    efghjk  lmno    pqrs    tuvw    NULL
987     654     321     dbca    kjhgfe  onml    srqp    xyz     NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom function if you are using **SQL Server 2014 or less**.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
GO
```

And use the above function in your select query.

```
SELECT Item
FROM dbo.SplitString('Apple,Mango,Banana,Guava')
```

[You can refer this for more info](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Split-and-convert-Comma-Separated-Delimited-String-to-Table-in-SQL-Server.aspx)

If you are using **SQL Server 2016**, then you can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

```
SELECT value  
FROM STRING_SPLIT('clothing,road,,touring,bike', ',')  
WHERE RTRIM(value) <> '';
```

Comment: Thank you @Jibin

I'm using SQL Server 2016, and the solution you provided really helped me. Special thanks